# How to optirun .sh file?

Tags: bumblebee

I managed to get as far as `optirun glxgear`, which worked perfectly, but I am unable to define settings for a specific shell script.

In its wiki it says this:

```
optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]
```

and I don't know what option has to be nor the application-parameter. (I'm really new) If my file is `/home/hon/hon.sh`, how can I execute it via terminal?

If I just type `optirun hon` or `optirun hon.sh` it shows this error:

```
/usr/bin/vglrun: 296: exec: hon: not found
```

there I try to find the file `/usr/bin/vglrun`. How can I run the shell scripts I need to run?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
optirun sh your_sh_file
```

Please note bumblebee uses nvdia card through virtualgl and the performance is very poor.

Possibly the command won't run   your game in nvdia mode. Because the the sh file is calling someother application. I think it would be better if you take a backup of sh file, then edit it to include optirun inside the sh file

Comment: how could i do that? specifically?

Comment: what site would be a good help (specific topic)
or how would I do it directly?

Comment: Open up the sh file in gedit. Identify where it is calling the application and put optirun over there. Or edit your question with content of the sh file

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `xyz` is program that doesn't exist.

```
$ optirun xyz
/usr/bin/vglrun: 296: exec: xyz: not found
```

So verify that the program exists where it's supposed to be

```
ls -l /home/hon/hon.sh
optirun /home/hon/hon.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the sh file exectable? if not then make it

```
chmod u+x hon.sh
```

If that doesn't help:

```
optirun bash
./hon.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
optirun sh ./PART TO .sh FILE/myfile.sh
```

Example to run Android-studio:

```
optirun sh /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```